# PHP mail form problems

Tags: php, forms, validation, webforms

I'm creating a simple mail form with checkboxes, a couple of input tabs, and a text input section. It uses PHP to retrieve the information then email it to a specific email. Right now I have it emailing to my own yahoo email just for testing. When I test the site on my hosting account jacobbuller.com/testsites/peacock/contact.php the form works perfectly and forwards the email from my generic "theski" server email. But when I upload the site to the actually live hosting account for peacockautoservice.com the contact form works - it executes and sends a ?msg=1 variable in the url - but I never receive the email in my Yahoo account...

Here's the PHP I am using to send the email.

```
<?php ob_start();
<?php 
$required_field = array('name', 'email', 'message');
foreach($required_field as $fieldname) {
if (!isset($_POST[$fieldname])) {
  $errors[] = $fieldname;
}}
if (empty($errors)) {
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$services = IsChecked('checkboxes', 'factory');
$services .= IsChecked('checkboxes', 'timing belt');
$services .= IsChecked('checkboxes', 'brakes');
$services .= IsChecked('checkboxes', 'computerized');
$services .= IsChecked('checkboxes', 'steering and suspension');
$services .= IsChecked('checkboxes', 'heating and air');
$services .= IsChecked('checkboxes', 'electrical');
$services .= IsChecked('checkboxes', 'other');
$body = "Customer:" . $name;
$body.= "Phone Number:" . $phone;
$body.= "Contact:" . $contact;
$body.= "Services:" . $services;
$body.= "Message:" . $message;
$to = "jcbbuller@yahoo.com";
$subject = "Peacock Auto Services Inquirey";
$from = $email;
$mailed = mail($to, $subject, $body, $from) or die("Error!");
 }
if($mailed) {
    redirect_to("../contact.php?msg=1");
}

 ?>
 <?php
 // IsChecked FUNCTION - Detemines what checkbox are/aren't checked on form.
 function IsChecked($postname, $value){ 
    if(!empty($_POST[$postname])) {
        foreach($_POST[$postname] as $job) {
        if ($job == $value) {
            $project = "  ". $value . "  ";
            return $project;

            }
        }
    }
  } //END IsChecked FUNCTION

 function redirect_to( $location = NULL ) {
    if ($location != NULL) {
        header("Location: {$location}");
        exit;
        }
     }   
 ?>
 <?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Please let me know if you see something wrong with the PHP above or if you know why their GoDaddy hosting account is not executing the email. I tried using their customer service network but they said that they can't help me with my code...

Comment: If it works on the test site but not the production site, the problem is probably with the PHP or SMTP configuration on the production site. There's nothing we can tell about that from the above script.

Comment: Check the spam folder. And then stop using the `mail()` function. Use PHPMailer/Swiftmailer.

Comment: I'll try one of these if I can't resolve the issue through my PHP alone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is mainly at server end. Mail function is working because of your check on it, if it had failed, it would have given you notification. So, mails are going definitely. If mail server is working properly at your production server, then check for SPAM folder at yahoo mail server. I would suggest you to ask your hosting provider to enable SPF and DKIM records because most of email providers requires sender authentication (if it is not a spam) and these records are helpful in it.

I can also see that your not using any headers, so I would suggest you to use extended headers to avoid providers identifying you as a spammer. I use below mentioned headers and my emails never go in spam on anyprovider, but again it depends on IP reputation of the server as well.

```
    $headers .= "Reply-To: Awaraleo <email@domain.org>\r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: Awaraleo <email@domain.org>\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: Awaraleo <email@domain.org>\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Organization: Awaraleo\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n";
```

and then use it like

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Here email@domain.org should be a valid email address created on the domain where this form is implemented.

Another authentic way is to use SMTP Authentication in coding.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it with the headers and let you know what happens.

Comment: Sure, and please select my reply as your answer if it helps you. Good Luck!

Comment: Well I'll be damned, it worked but it's going in my bulk email... by asking my hosting provider to enable SPF and DKIM records would that give me a better chance of it not going into my spam folder? Either way super excited! Thanks!

Comment: Its great to know that you are out of problem now. :)) Ofcourse those records help because they are designed specially to overcome such issues. But again, a lot will depend upon the IP reputation of your server, therefore choosing a good/efficient host is all important. Another helping activity is to move your email from bulk folder to inbox by marking it "not as spam". Do it on all major providers like yahoo, gmail, hotmail. If you have multiple accounts on them, that will be more good, because they build reputation of an IP/domain based on feedback of their users.